# Why is my for loop with (4^i >= x) as condition becoming infinite in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

This is my code for a leveling system (every level requires 4^level XP):

```
var x = 0; // x will change
var y = 0;
for (var i = 0; 4^i >= x; i++) {
    y = i;
}
console.log(y);
```

However, when I run this code, it ends up freezing the page and making it unresponsive. I can only assume that it is an infinite loop. Is there a syntax error in this code?

Comment: `^` does not mean what you think it does.

Comment: There is no sintax error as it is running but ^ in js is not exponentiation. Use Math.pow or the more recent ** operator

Comment: Use `**` in modern browsers.

Comment: `Math.pow()` !== `^`